# Use AVCaptureSession to Read Audio Files

Tags: swift, macos, audio, avcapturesession, avaudioengine

I currently have a working macOS app for music visualization using `AVAudioEngine` to read music files.  It contains the following swift code (extraneous code omitted for clarity):

```
import AVFoundation
class AudioManager: ObservableObject {
    static let audioManager = AudioManager()
    var selectedSongURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "music", withExtension: "mp3"
    var engine : AVAudioEngine!
    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    do {
        let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: selectedSongURL!)
        player.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    player.play()
}
```

The app contains other code to allow the user to change the selectedSongURL to a different file.

I would like to change my app to use `AVCaptureSession` instead of `AVAudioEngine` to take advantage of the finer granularity it offers.  There are many code examples showing how to use `AVCaptureSession` with a microphone input.

But, I was unable to find any code or tutorials on how to use it with input from reading music files (similar to the code above).

I'm not sure it's even possible. Is it possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if I explained WHY I want to switch from using AVAudioEngine to AVCaptureSession as the audio capture part of my music visualization app:  Using AVAudioEngine's tap-on-bus approach, the finest-grain audio sampling I can get (on my 2017 iMac running macOS Big Sur) is 4,410 samples every 0.1 seconds. On the other hand, using AVCaptureSession with a microphone input, the corresponding numbers are 512 samples every 0.0116 seconds.  This provides much lower latency and much faster refresh rates.  If only I could figure out a way for AVCaptureSession to read audio files ...

Answer (score 1):

At the WWDC 2021, I requested an AVFoundation Lab session to ask this question.  I ended up talking with an engineer on the Camera Capture team, but fortunately he was very familiar with Apple audio APIs.  He confirmed to me that AVCaptureSession is intended to interface with hardware devices only - and hence would not work for reading song files as I desired.

He did bring to my attention two software products (Soundflower and Loopback) that tap into Apple's audio subsystem bus and allow developer apps (like mine) to read raw audio data from them as though they were a "microphone input".

He also promised to convey to the AVAudioEngine team my desire that they improve the tap-on-bus granularity to provide blocks of audio samples more frequently than every 0.1 seconds.